# How to send server messages to dropzone

Tags: django, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js and Django to upload files and process it and show messages based on processes which are done in the server side, How I can send the messages from Django view to my dropzone component, I can see that there is a red cross when the server generates an error, how I can put my own message on that? 
This is my view:

```
   @login_required
   def upload_file(request):
    error=''
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file'] :
           ##doing something and based on that generate error
            error='My message.....'
            return render(request,'app/inputFile_pannel.html', {
               'error':error})           
    return render(request,'app/inputFile_pannel.html', {
       'error':error})
```

and this is the dropzone options in the template file:

```
       Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
           clickable:true,
           method:"post",
           withCredentials:true,
           paramName: 'file',
           autoProcessQueue :false,
           uploadMultiple:false,
           forceFallback:false
}
```

and this is the form in my template:

```
<form  method="POST"  action="{% url 'upload_file' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" >
                                    {% csrf_token %}
```

when I want to show the error using {{error}} in the template it doesn't work,  when I change the forceFallback to true everything is working well and the errors are shown properly, but the form changes to simple file input and is not a dropzone any more. How I can send my messages from view to this template? Is it possible to have access to the red cross message which is appeared in thumbnail files in dropzone? could anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found the answer!
I put it here for people who have the same problem:
If you want to send a message from Django view to Dropzone and you want it to be presented as a red message in Dropzone you should send a Json response including a context with "error" key and value would be your message kile this:

```
 error="My message..."
 return JsonResponse({'error':error},status=400)
```